# NullPointerException while trying to setTitle() for Preference

Tags: java, android

I have an Account Information Activity and I need to show the account info which I get from the internet to the user using the PreferenceFragment.

And I'm trying to set a Title for a Preference but everytime I got a `java.lang.NullPointerExcption` while I was trying to do that.

So what's the problem and what should I do?

**AccountData.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class AccountData extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();


        try {
            PrefsFragment PF = new PrefsFragment();
            PF.setAccountName();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.account_data);
        }

        public void setAccountName() {
            Preference AccountName = (Preference) findPreference("account_name");
            AccountName.setTitle("Account Name");
        }
    }
}
```

**account_data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/account" >
        <Preference
            android:key="account_name"
            android:selectable="false"
            android:summary="@string/account_name"
            android:title="@string/none" />
        <Preference
            android:key="account_type"
            android:selectable="false"
            android:summary="@string/account_type"
            android:title="@string/none" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

_*****Edited*****_

***The Stacktrace***

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.AccountData}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.app.AccountData$PrefsFragment.setAccountName(AccountData.java:39)
    at com.example.app.AccountData.onCreate(AccountData.java:21)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Is the `onCreate` method (`PreferenceFragment`) for class `PrefsFragment` called implicitly or do you explicitly have to call it?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Sorry I couldn't understand what you mean? I'm stilling a beginner Android Developer and I have a lot of mistakes, so could you please explain what did you mean? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the call into onResume() of your fragment.

```
public void onResume() {
        Preference AccountName = (Preference) findPreference("account_name");
        AccountName.setTitle("Account Name");
}
```

I've never used a "PreferenceFragment," but it's probably because the UI hasn't been initialized yet. The call to onCreate is from the UI thread and will block other UI transactions, such as adding a fragment. So even though you've added a fragment to your UI, it's a delayed call and hasn't gotten any of it's callbacks yet.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
        PrefsFragment PF = new PrefsFragment();
        PF.setAccountName();
```

does work, as this does not call onCreate.

Use only one instance of PrefsFragment.

Comment: you should call setAccountName in PrefsFragment.onCreate or onStart (or onAttach, i'm not sure)